# Create unknown number of columns in a data frame based on input

Tags: r

I need to create a data.frame in R based on an input vector. The vector has a name for each item and can have any length. I need to create the data.frame with part of its column names the same as the vector's item names.

```
> v
a b c 
1 2 3 


> df
  age weight a b c
1  18    118 1 2 3
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `cbind(anotherdf, data.frame(as.list(v)))`

Comment: thanks! > df <- data.frame(age = 18, weight = 118)
> cbind(df, as.list(vec))
  age weight a b c
1  18    118 1 2 3